# Can two light sources be on a dimmer within the same 3-panel switch?

Tags: electrical, bathroom, switch, code-compliance, california

Our GC's electrician recently installed a new 3-panel switch in our California bathroom to control two light sources and a dehumidifier/fan.  I had wanted both light sources to be on the dimmer, but the electrician said only one can be on a dimmer according to code, and proceeded with putting the recessed ceiling lights on the dimmer assuming we'd prefer that over the dimmer-compatible wall fixture, which is now simply an ON/OFF switch, apparently to comply with code.  The dehumidifier is automatic (don't ever have to touch it)/fan switch is manual, but does the story with the lights all sound legit? Can we really *not* have both the recessed lights *and* the wall fixture on dedicated dimmers in the same 3-panel switch?

Comment: What type of "three panel switch" do you have?  I've never heard of that combination of lights not being allowed on dimmers. Maybe our West Coast guys will chime in..

Comment: Did your electrician actually provide you with a citation to the Code section that they said prohibited what you want?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel He did not and that's why I'm wondering and trying to research it, but I'm a newbie.  He simply said that it would not pass code if he did both light sources on the dimmer.

Comment: @JACK what type?  How may types of 3-panel switches are there?  Perhaps I can answer in the form of a multiple choice question?

Comment: How many watts are a) the recessed cans and b) the wall fixture?  Also, what make and model of dimmer did the electrician install?

Comment: There are many types. A picture, make or model might help.

Comment: Make/model of the panel is LUTRON®: first switch on the panel is a motion-sensor ON/OFF switch for the wall fixture, middle switch is the dimmer slide for the 3 recessed cans, third/final switch is the ON/OFF fan/dehumidifier switch.  Trying to figure out how to add a picture on this thread, but I don't see how to do that.  I do have a picture though, if it would be helpful.  Thanks all!

Comment: Wall fixture sticker: "Risk of fire, use MAX, 60watt or smaller, 120 Volt, Type A bulbs 120 VAC 60Hz".  Recessed cans: likely 60watt, but not certain because electrician did not tell me when he installed.

Comment: @DeanBach -- hit "edit" in "share edit ..." at the bottom left of your question, then use the "mountain and sun" button to add your pictures

Comment: "if he did both light sources on *the* dimmer." - sounds like he only had one dimmer with him. **Both on the same dimmer could be more than the acceptable wattage of a single dimmer.** It wouldn't be *up to code* but if an inspector caught that then you got the short stick. "I had wanted both light sources to be on *the* dimmer" again, you used the singular.

Comment: Can two light sources be on *the same* dimmer ? As long as the total wattage doesn't exceed (usually 600W) the rating on the dimmer.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have a "3 gang" switch.

I don't know your local code but your installer's statement sounds like nonsense.  You note you have recessed ceiling *lights*.  Plural.  Obviously you don't need one dimmer switch per ceiling light, that would be ridiculous.  So from the start the idea you can only have one light per switch is nonsensical.

There is a limit to how much power (total watts of all lights) your dimmer can control but if you're using LED bulbs it's extremely unlikely you are exceeding the power limit of even the smallest cheapest dimmer.

I can't even guess why your electrician would do this.  Can't say he's lazy because what he did is more work.

One thing is possible:  If the light bulbs on a dimmer are not all exactly the same brand and wattage, they may not dim uniformly.  Perhaps your electrician was worried about that, or other unknown problems in the way dissimilar lights would behave on one dimmer, causing you to complain later on and so he just said the magic C word to avoid having to get into it with you.

Note that if you combine the lights onto a single dimmer you'll either have a switch that does nothing, or you'll have to buy a special cover plate with two openings and a blank.

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation makes no sense as you are talking about "the dimmer" in one part of it and "dedicated dimmers" elsewhere.

The claim by the electrician makes no logical sense and I would contact the local building authority on it.  1, 2, or 3 separate can lights is exactly electrically equivalent to 2 separate light bulbs in a single overhead fixture on a dimmer which is certainly not prohibited by code.  I would contact the building authority and ask about this.  You can do what you want with your electrician but I know what I would do (after getting clarification from the code authority) and it would definitely not be nice.  I'm so sick of people claiming code or legalities as a reason for not doing something when the real reason is they are too lazy to look up the relevant statue or code.